# matlab Out of memory . Type HELP MEMORY for your options

Tags: matlab, memory, out-of-memory, pca

I use pcacov command in matlab with pcacov(20000*20000 matrix) input parameters, but matlab can't handel it with memory and show error:

> `pcacov matlab Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.`

How can i solve this problem with coding or setting in the matlab and with out add or change any hardware memory or change pc.

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly how you call `pcacov`? The input should be a matrix, according to the [documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/pcacov.html).

Comment: Dear stewie, sorry i edit it ((20000,20000)>(20000*20000 matrix) ), inpute parameter are 20,000 * 20,000 dimention matrix. but matlab can't handel this big matrix for pcacov. can i divide pcacov in several command? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you can fix this problem without adding more memory. The matrix that MATLAB uses is as big as your physical memory. You can consider some algorithms use partitioned matrix, or you may try tall arrays in MATLAB. But, these technologies make research more complex.

Comment: for svd from big data in matlab we can use 'svds' to get top eigenvalues, and also i found 'lmsvd' solution, 'lmsvd' is a matlab solver for computing truncated (dominant) singular value decompositions of relatively large matrices(https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46875-lmsvd-m).  seem as there is no any way, except to add hardware.